# Refreshing div or page once with JS or jQuery / Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I want to reload the div or web page only once for a Flask web app I am working on but as I don't know JS well I am stuck with a loop instead of it refreshing just once.

Why am I trying to do this?

Before getting to this page a user inputs data and it does calculations and then through Selenium, it does a website screenshot the process takes too long so when the user hits enter it does the calcs and then redirects to the new page once on that page I call a fx that submits in the background via ajax the selenium function, a gif is loaded instead of the screenshot.

The goal is that once the ajax route completes, the div or page reloads only once to replace the gif and shows the screenshot (which I did through if/else in Jinja) Hope that made sense if not let me know.

This is the div I want to work on

```
<div id="siteimg" class="c">
{% if a.imgofsite != "" %}
  <img class="c" src="{{ url_for('static', filename = '' + a.imgofsite ) }}" style="overflow: hidden;">
{% else %}
  <img class="c" src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/load.gif') }}" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <h5 class="c" style="overflow: hidden;">RENDERING SCREENSHOT</h5>
{% endif %}
```

Below is the JS I am using to submit the form and then call  it.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function img_load() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/siteimage/{{ a._id }}',
              });
             }
    </script>
    <script>img_load();</script>
```

What I have tried:
This put me in a continuous loop

```
location.reload(true);
```

This gave me no response when I added it to the ajax call block

```
function refresh() {

setTimeout(function () {
    location.reload()
}, 100);
```

}

This one put me in a continuous loop as well

```
$("#siteimg").load(location.href + " #siteimg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

**`SetTimeout`** is will recall the ajax specific to the div `siteimg` after 2 seconds.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $.get(window.location.href + " #siteimg", function(data) {
    //empty old contents
    $('#siteimg').empty().append($(data).find('#siteimg').children());

    //recall after contents are emptied
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/siteimage/{{ a._id }}'
    });
    $('#siteimg').append("<img src='https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg'>");
    $('#siteimg').append(
      "<img src='https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg'>"
    );

  });
  console.log($("#text").html());
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Doesn't work stays in a loop, remember I said i want it to refresh only once and doesn't refresh the div nor page. But thank you for the try.

Comment: Does clearing the divs content work? this is just an example, Run sample in your project...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to update the content of your div with the received data something like:

```
<script> 
    function img_load() {
       $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/siteimage/{{ a._id }}',
         success: function(response) {
                       $('#siteimg').append(response);
                  },
         error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                       console.log('Ajax status: ' + jqXHR.status + ', error: ' exeption);
                }
      });
     }
  </script>
```

Comment: Take a look at the modified answer @JasonMartinez

Comment: <script>
    var delayInMilliseconds = 60000; // 1 min
    function img_load() {
       $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/siteimage/{{ a._id }}',
       },

          setTimeout(function() {
            $('#siteimg').load(document.URL +  ' #siteimg');
       }, delayInMilliseconds)
       )
     }
     img_load()
  </script> I got it to work with this.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the browsers `sessionStorage` to track if the page was reloaded or not after the first visit.

At the end of your html insert the following js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem('reloaded')) {
        // Page was not reloaded until last visit: do some stuff
        sessionStorage.setItem('reloaded', true); // remeber the following reload for the next time
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.reload();
        }, 100);
    }else{
        // Page was reloaded: clear your flag for the next visit
        sessionStorage.removeItem('reloaded');
    }
</script>
```

If you chose to show a modal that the user informs about the reload (what would good practise in my opinion) you should increase the `setTimeout` value from `100` to maybe `2500`.

You can try it here (with addional console output): http://fiddle.bplaced.net/53414316/

#### Edit:

After reading your question again what you need is an `ajax` request. Reloading your site is just a workaround.

Although my solution should do what you have ask for - Andersons answer is what you should look for.

Comment: I tried this code in addition to mine like this but it did nothing.

Comment: I had a typo in `sessionStorage`. The flag has never been set :) fixed now

Comment: Just tried it doesn't do anything and I tried it in Chrome and Firefox. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The code works, maybe you did not recognize the refresh. Here is an example with 5 seconds delay and additional console output: http://fiddle.bplaced.net/53414316/

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. First, let me say thank you to all who were providing answers and editing to assist me in this issue.
For right now this is my solution. If any issues come up with this I definitely will add that info.

Once I am done with this project I definitely will be doing some JS/jQuery and Ajax courses.

```
 <script>
        var delayInMilliseconds = 60000; // 1 min
    function img_load() {
       $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/siteimage/{{ a._id }}',
       },

          setTimeout(function() {
            $('#siteimg').load(document.URL +  ' #siteimg');
       }, delayInMilliseconds)
       )
     }
     img_load()
  </script>
```